# How to evaluate if a number is cube

Tags: c#, math, integer, double, decimal

I'm trying to calculate the cube root of a number to check if it's a perfect cube. Unfortunately the .NET Framework has no built-in function for that. So in order to calculate the cube root of a number I have to use the `Math.Pow` function:

```
double cubeRoot = Math.Pow(125, (double)1 / 3);
```

When I try to evaluate if the cube root is an integer it outputs `false`, yet 125 is a perfect cube:

```
Console.WriteLine(cubeRoot % 1 == 0);
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to round and check if the cube of the cube root is equal to the original value

```
double input = 125;
double cubeRoot = Math.Pow(input, 1.0/3.0);
double c = Math.Round(cubeRoot);
Console.WriteLine(c*c*c == input);
```

Note that `Math.Pow(input, 1.0/3.0)` is not the most accurate way to calculate cube root because `1.0/3.0` is not exactly representable in binary (and decimal). But since we're rounding the result to int anyway, the output will not be affected

.NET Core 2.1 added [`Math.Cbrt(double)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cbrt?view=netcore-2.1) which can be used to get a correct result in double precision, though I'm not sure if it's faster than the `Math.Pow()` solution or not

Comment: Thank you for your answer. William's answer was indeed incorrect as I looked for other cubes.